# List organic group members from the current user group on his profile page

Tags: views, organic-groups

I am new to organic groups, I ran into a problem, I am a member of some organic group, I need to list other members of same group on my profile page, Trying to display it using views but no luck :(,  I am working on drupal 7 with Organic group 7.x-2.9

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to answer you last time.! Sorry. You said your were happy with some code so here it is.

Step 1: The custom module.

```
function CUSTOM_MODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args){ 
// Select our view
    if($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME' and $display_id == 'DISPLAY_NAME') {
    // Get User ID from url
        $view_user = user_load(arg(1));
        $user_groups = array();
        // Get Group IDs
            $items = field_get_items('user', $view_user, 'og_user_node');
                foreach($items as $item) {
                    $user_groups[] = $item['target_id'];
                 }
    // Join like 4+78+345 for Views
        $user_groups_args = implode("+", $user_groups);
    // Send IDs to view
        $args[0] = $user_groups_args;   
    }
}
```

Create a module and change what's in caps. Be aware that that module doesn't do any checking.. Only use it for user/* or node/* etc. where the second argument is an integer.

Step 2: The View

1. In your View, add the `OG membership: Group ID` contextual filter
   (make sure it's first in the list).
2. Under its settings under More, check `Allow multiple values`.
3. Because some users may be in more than one group, go to `Query settings` under `Other` and check `Distinct`.

That should be it.